# How to extract text from PDF image

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I wanted to extract data from PDF which has image, and the image is form where letter will be inside small boxes for example, `name : t e s t`, here each and every word will be inside square box.

I have tried tesseract OCR could not get the desired result.

I have tried commercial ABBYY worked but I wanted to use java based free API.

below is the example
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicomsoft OCR SDK which is a free SDK has extracted the text from my PDF and results are satisfactory

it supports really large technologies, Now I am trying to integrate it into my application

Link https://www.nicomsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

As far as free goes in OCR, Tesseract is as good as it gets.

Alternatively you could look at the [Windows 10 UWP OCR offering](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/08/optical-character-recognition-ocr-for-windows-10/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the free ones out there, but you can definitely try TotalPDFConverterOCR

It has wide range of things like converting to doc,images etc.

Comment: it did not worked using with the software mentioned, this is internally using Tesseract